# Getting the youngest and oldest ages out of an array

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java and this is the problem that I am facing. Currently, I have a program that asks the user for 10 names and their ages. It then displays each of the names and their ages in order from highest to lowest. What I want to do is below this, display who is the oldest and who is the youngest.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class array2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {


        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        input.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        int numofpeople = 10;
        Person[] persons = new Person[numofpeople];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numofpeople; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the person's name: ");
            String person = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the persons's age: ");
            int age = (Integer) input.nextInt();
            persons[i] = new Person(person, age);
        }
        
        System.out.print("Name" + "\tAge");
        System.out.print("\n----" + "\t----\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++){
          System.out.println(persons[i].person + "\t" + persons[i].age);
        }

        System.out.println("The oldest person is: ");
        System.out.println("The youngest person is: ");


    }

}

public class Person{
  public String person;
  public Integer age;
  public Person(String s, Integer g){
    this.person = s;
    this.age = g;
  }
}
```

I am not quite sure how to do this, maybe similar to formatting it from largest age to smallest? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to finish an array early using a keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716061/trying-to-finish-an-array-early-using-a-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this with your array, without using any other special collections.

1. Let your class `Person` implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and implement the `compareTo()` method.

   ```
   public class Person implements Comparable {  
       @Override
       public int compareTo(Person p) {
           return this.age - p.age;
       }
   }
   ```

   To sort the array with this method, it can be simply do:

   ```
   Arrays.sort(persons);
   ```
2. Create a Comparator that contains the logic to compare the different `Person` instances.

   ```
   public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

       @Override
       public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
           return p1.age - p2.age;
       }
   }
   ```

   Then to be used like this:

   ```
   Arrays.sort(persons, new PersonComparator());
   ```
3. Or create an anonymous comparator like this:

   ```
   Arrays.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
           return p1.age - p2.age;
       }
   });
   ```

After that the array is sorted, then you can get the first and last item of the array like:

```
Person youngest = persons[0];
Person oldest = persons[persons.length-1];
```

Comment: Hello! This works for the most part but when I am trying to enter ``` 

oldest = persons[0];
youngest = persons[persons.length-1];

 ```

it gives me an error that says cannot find symbol, which Im assuming is because I need to declare it as an integer or string, but I cannot declare it as either. What do I do?

Comment: I updated the answer. The objects you retrieve from the `persons[]` array are of type `Person` of course. So they have to declared accordingly: `Person youngest = persons[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Use [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) to maintain the persons object in Order. Provide comparator based on age to sort objects by age.

```
TreeSet<Person> persons = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(person -> person.age));
```

Then use [first()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#first--) and [last()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#last--) methods of TreeSet to get oldest and youngest person object

```
"The oldest person is: " + persons.first().age
"The youngest person is: " + persons.last().age
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just make the Person class "comparable", and then use the Arrays.sort()  method to sort the array of persons according to their age.
Of course, with the ordered array, the first element will be the youngest person and the last element will be the oldest one.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        input.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        int numofpeople = 4;
        Person[] persons = new Person[numofpeople];

        for (int i = 0; i < numofpeople; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the person's name: ");
            String person = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the persons's age: ");
            int age = (Integer) input.nextInt();
            persons[i] = new Person(person, age);
        }
        
        Arrays.sort(persons);

        System.out.print("Name" + "\tAge");
        System.out.print("\n----" + "\t----\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(persons[i].person + "\t" + persons[i].age);
        }

        System.out.println("The oldest person is: " + persons[numofpeople-1].person);
        System.out.println("The youngest person is: "+ persons[0].person);

    }

}

class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    public String person;
    public Integer age;

    public Person(String s, Integer g) {
        this.person = s;
        this.age = g;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (this.age>o.age?1:-1);
    }
}
```