# How to break out of a loop and print the contents of an array

Tags: java

How can I break out of a loop when the user enters "done" and print the contents of what the user entered? Also, I would like to be able to find the smallest element of the array and the largest element of the array during the printing.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class array2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        input.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        int numofpeople = 10;
        Person[] persons = new Person[numofpeople];

        for (int i = 0; i < numofpeople; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the person's name: ");
            String person = input.next();

            if(person.equals("done")){break;}

            System.out.print("Enter the persons's age: ");
            int age = (Integer) input.nextInt();
            persons[i] = new Person(person, age);
        }


    }

}

class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    public String person;
    public Integer age;
    public Person(String s, Integer g) {
        this.person = s;
        this.age = g;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return (this.age>o.age?1:-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should check "break" vs "continue" , break will end the for loop when conditions is met. continue will skip that particular input and proceed with rest of inputs.

Comment: "program finishes *rather than displaying the answers I have previously wrote*." which part of your code is responsible for display anything? Where is it (since it is not inside main method, nor is it called from it)?

Comment: IMO, the single most important technique for working out why your code doesn't work is **reading it**.  Seriously, there is no code in the program in your question to do what you are saying: print the results.

Comment: @catman2 I just realized that you asked the same question 3 times. This is not the right way to ask for help. I flagged each as a duplicate of this one, but in the future please do not post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement will make the program leave the `for` loop. You have no code to print the array outside of the `for` loop. In fact, there is no code outside of the loop. This will make your program exit since it is in the `main` method. So you need code to print the array.

Complete Solution Given all comments below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Array2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList();
        int numOfPeople = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPeople; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the person's name: ");
            String person = input.nextLine();
            if (person.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.print("Enter the persons's age: ");
            int age = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            persons.add(new Person(person, age));
        }
        //Collections.sort(persons); //not sorting anymore
        for (Person person : persons) {
            System.out.println(person.name + ": " + person.age);
        }
        Person youngestPerson = getYoungest(persons);
        Person oldestPerson = getOldest(persons);
        System.out.println("Youngest: " + youngestPerson.name + ": " + youngestPerson.age);
        System.out.println("Oldest: " +oldestPerson.name + ": " + oldestPerson.age);

    }

    public static Person getYoungest(ArrayList<Person> people) {
        Person youngestPerson = null;
        for (Person person : people) {
            if (youngestPerson == null || person.age < youngestPerson.age) {
                youngestPerson = person;
            }
        }
        return youngestPerson;

    }

    public static Person getOldest(ArrayList<Person> people) {
        Person oldestPerson = null;
        for (Person person : people) {
            if (oldestPerson == null || person.age > oldestPerson.age) {
                oldestPerson = person;
            }
        }
        return oldestPerson;

    }

    protected static class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

        protected String name;
        protected int age;

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Person o) {
            return (this.age > o.age ? 1 : -1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224234/discussion-on-answer-by-thetechnician94-trying-to-finish-an-array-early-using-a).